# Python - My programmed error system shows me an error even if I have got an answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is below:

```
import re
import csv
import sys
import random

def RestartProgram():

    restart = input("Would you like to restart? Y/N")
    yes = "y" or "Y"

    if restart == yes:
        PhoneSupport()

def PhoneSupport():

    error = 0

    f = open("C:\PhoneSupp CSV.csv", "r")

    rows = re.split("\n", f.read())

    userInput = input("What has happened to your phone?")
    randInt = random.randint(0,9999)

    if userInput == "":
        print("You have not entered any problem.")
        RestartProgram()

    for index, row in enumerate(rows): #Loop that splits the rows into cells
        cells = row.split(',')
        if userInput in cells:
            error = 0
            print("A Solution has been found!:")
            print("")
            print(cells)
        elif userInput not in cells:
            error = 1


    if error == 1:
        print("No Solution has been found - Your support ticket is: " + str(randInt))
        print("")
        RestartProgram()
    elif error == 0:
        RestartProgram()

PhoneSupport()
```

Comment: Please describe your error! As it stands it's not clear what you're asking!!

Comment: Could you please formulate a question? What is happening? What should happen?

Comment: It should give a solution to a user's problem with their phone. If it gives an answer, no error message should appear. If not solution is found, then the  error message should show alongside a random integer

Comment: So the elif state is entered everytime, right?

Comment: @Dschoni Right, but it sets error = 1 regardless and thats my problem

Comment: Can you check with one example, that your userInput really exists in cells? Because it doesn't seem to. Or the formatting is wrong or...

Comment: Well, all the times I have entered the exact string from the CSV file into the userInput, it shows the solution AND the error. So it definitely exists unless you mean something else... @Dschoni

Comment: You should refactor that code. At the moment you use your function as "jump points" leading to a recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not breaking your `for` loop after it finds the solution.
Add a `break` statement after you print the error. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much. For others who needed it, I placed the break under the print(cells) line.